# How to get an array using`map`

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap

For my PDF table using gem prawn, I want this:

```
[
  ["FIELDS", "RESULT"],
  ["会社名", "company 1"],
  ["担当者名", "contact person 1"],
  ["電話番号/FAX番号", "contact 1"],
  ["E-mailアドレス", "email 1"],
  ["会社名", "company 2"],
  ["担当者名", "contact person 2"],
  ["電話番号/FAX番号", "contact 2"],
  ["E-mailアドレス", "email 2"],
  ["会社名", "company 3"],
  ["担当者名", "contact person 3"],
  ["電話番号/FAX番号", "contact 3"],
  ["E-mailアドレス", "email 3"]
]
```

Here is my code:

```
[["FIELDS", "RESULT"]] +
@customer.customer_details.map do |cd|
  ["会社名", cd.company_name.to_s] +
  ["担当者名", cd.name.to_s] +
  ["電話番号/FAX番号", cd.contact_number.to_s] +
  ["E-mailアドレス", cd.email.to_s]
end
```

and, I got this:

```
[
  ["FIELDS", "RESULT"],
  [
    "会社名", "company 1", "担当者名", "contact person 1", "電話番号/FAX番号", "contact 1", "E-mailアドレス", "email 1",
    "会社名", "company 2", "担当者名", "contact person 2", "電話番号/FAX番号", "contact 2", "E-mailアドレス", "email 2",
    "会社名", "company 3", "担当者名", "contact person 3", "電話番号/FAX番号", "contact 3", "E-mailアドレス", "email 3"
  ]
]
```

Can someone help me how to generate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another way,

```
result = [["FIELDS", "RESULT"]]
@customer.customer_details.each do |cd|
  result += [["会社名", cd.company_name.to_s],
  ["担当者名", cd.name.to_s],
  ["電話番号/FAX番号", cd.contact_number.to_s],
  ["E-mailアドレス", cd.email.to_s] ]
end

p result
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It is not good. It will add the header in each details

Comment: no budy, i have tested it and it gives only one header.
`result = [["FIELDS", "RESULT"]]
[1,2].each do |cd|
  result += [["会社名", "a#{cd}"],
  ["担当者名", "b#{cd}"]]
end
result`

And its result is what u want, `[["FIELDS", "RESULT"], ["会社名", "a1"], ["担当者名", "b1"], ["会社名", "a2"], ["担当者名", "b2"]]`

Comment: ah, sorry I didn't notice that you've used `each` instead of map. THANK YOU.